# Connecting a Google Cloud Run instance to MongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, mongodb-atlas

I'm trying to connect a Cloud Run service to a MongoDB Atlas server without having to whitelist all IPs but I can't manage to do so.
I've tried [this](https://ahmet.im/blog/cloud-run-static-ip/) tutorial but it didn't work with mongo. I tried SSH tunneling but it also didn't work.

Comment: As the author of the tutorial I can say that it’s for http/https proxying, so it's expected it doesn't work for mongodb wire protocol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update (October 2020):**

You can now configure static egress IPs for your Cloud Run containers connecting to external endpoints (such as MongoDB Atlas) by using a VPC connector and configuring a Cloud NAT.

Read the setup guide here: https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/static-outbound-ip

Answer (score 5):

It's, for now, the right tutorial. In the future, you will be able to nat Cloud Run outgoing traffic with Cloud NAT. I hope soon. (Cloud Run is now compliant with serverless VPC access, and thus you can reach your proxy compute engine directly with the private IP, it's safer!)

The other solution is to use [MongoDB Atlas peering](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/security-vpc-peering/) with your VPC. And because [Cloud Run is now compliant with serverless VPC connector](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/configure-serverless-vpc-access), you can reach privately your MongoDB Atlas through VPC.

*Note: But it works only with paid Mongo instances*